# How to use require function inside a Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to import fs of Nodejs in electron, in which I am trying to use require function.

However, I am getting error require is not defined. How to fix this? Do we need to add special configuration for electron and Nodejs integration? I am writing below script in my `index.html` file:

```
function myFunction() { 
    var fs = require('fs')
}
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system

Comment: `require` is a server side (node.js) function and won't work in client side scripts. Placing the above code in an HTML file will not work.

Comment: Please elaborate on your electron application and describe more specifically where you are trying to use `require()`.  I node.js code, `require()` is built in.  In client-side display technology (like an HTML/browser-like engine, `require()` is not built in.

Comment: This should work...  Are you loading any third-party libraries in the renderer process?  Are you sure you didn't set `node-integration: false` (which would cause `require` to not be defined in the renderer process)?

Answer (score 0):

In regards to `require( 'fs' )` I think it only works in the main process. If you trying from the renderer process, try using require using the `remote` module.

```
var remote = require( 'remote' );

var fs = remote.require( 'fs' );
```

Comment: The above should cover you, but your question may need more information.  How are you creating your project? (npm init ?).  Are you sure that electron-prebuilt is showing as a dependency in your package.json ?  Can you tell us which node you are running `node -v` & `npm -v`?

Comment: `require('fs')` works just fine directly from the renderer process as well (at least, assuming `require` exists and has not been overridden, hence my question in my comment to the original question).  IIRC the only things you need `remote` to require are main-process-specific modules e.g. browser-window, dialog, etc.

Comment: just linking some docs, for clarification: https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md

Answer (score 0):

very early in your index.html I that

```
if (window.require) {
  window.requireNode = window.require;
  window.require = undefined;
}
```

and then later

```
<script src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

so I can do

```
window.requireNode("remote")
```

to load "node electron" stuff in my webpage

and the traditiona

```
window.require("my/module")
```

to load my modules